# Question about Eulerian Circuits and Graph Connectedness

Tags: graph-theory, eulerian-path

I read a theorem in a Graph Theory Introductory text. It says "If a pseudograph G has an Eulerian Circuit, then it is connected and every vertex of the graph G has even degree."

Is it necessary that if a graph G has an Eulerian Circuit, then it is connected? What if there are isolated vertices in the graph G? I would greatly appreciate it if you can please clarify this for me.

Comment: I edited the tag group theory and replaced it with graph theory and eulerian path.

Comment: @TryingHardToBecomeAGoodPrSlvr: The definition depends on the author. Check out http://mathworld.wolfram.com/EulerianGraph.html

Comment: @Mortiz I am reading the book Pearls In Graph Theory by N. Hartsfield G. Ringel. Theorem 3.1.1 from that book states that "If a pseudograph has an Eulerian circuit, then G is connected and degree of every vertex is even."  I wonder what happens to graphs with isolated vertices. Why does the graph need to be connected even if an Eulerian Circuit exists when there are isolated vertices? If you wish to see the book, please visit the website https://proofits.files.wordpress.com/2012/09/0123285526_graphtheory.pdf

Comment: I just wanted to mention that I found a website which supplies the correction. The website is https://www.math.binghamton.edu/zaslav/Oldcourses/381.S11/ann.html and the theorem after correction is: Theorem 3.1.1 (corrected). If a pseudograph G has an Eulerian circuit, then G is connected (except for isolated vertices) and the degree of every vertex is even.

Answer (score 0):

To be an Eulerian Circuit, all vertices must have an even degree and the graph must act as a cycle. The graph must be connected as isolated vertices would have degrees of 0 so therefore it would not be an eulerian graph.